# Azure Application Insights stopped logging exceptions

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I have an Azure Worker Role logging custom events, metrics, request and exceptions to AppInsights - all good. But like a week ago I noticed that exceptions stopped coming through. The chart I have in the Metrics Explorer does not show any recent ones anymore. 
This coincides with a release were we upgraded the Microsoft.ApplicationInsights Nuget to v2.2.0-beta2 - but I am not sure if it is related..

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Exception just started to show up in the portal when I moved to the next pricing tier. Looks like I was been throttled..